# Unable to break lease and expand Ubuntu OS disk on Azure

Tags: azure, ubuntu, azure-blob-storage

I have a classic deployed Ubuntu VM. My goal is to expend the OS disk size of that VM. I am following a guide to exapand the OS disk using CloudXplorer.

If I try to break the lease using CloudXplorer, it gives me an error "The blob is being used by the system". Under my vhd blob properties blade on Azure Portal it states:
Lease status: Locked
Lease state: Leased
Lease duration: Infinite

The VM is shut down (deallocated).

If I go to Disks blade under the VM in ARM, I can see the detach option is grayed out.

How can I break the lease for my OS disk so I can expand it?

Again, this not an ARM deployed VM.

Comment: You had better use PowerShell cmdlet to expand OS disk, you only need execute one cmdlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my knowledge, you could expand your OS disk by using PowerShell cmdlet. It works for me.

1.Stop your VM by using Portal or PowerShell.

2.Expand OS disk by using Power Shell.

```
Update-AzureDisk –DiskName "<Disk name>" -Label "ResiZedOS" -ResizedSizeInGB <Size in GB>
```

Example:

```
Update-AzureDisk -DiskName "shui-shui-0-201703140941510948" -Label "ReSizedOs" -ResizedSizeInGB 50
```

You could find DiskName by using Portal.

[image]

3.Start your VM and `ssh` to your VM and check.

```
root@shui:~# fdisk -l|grep /dev/sda
Disk /dev/sda: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
/dev/sda1  *     2048 104857566 104855519  50G 83 Linux
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but I believe this only works if the VM was deployed using the ARM model. Mine was deployed with the classical one.

Comment: No, It works for classic VM. I test by using classic VM. Also, If you break lease disk with VM, you need redeploy VM using VHD. If posdible, you could try to use my method.

Comment: Ok, I see. I get "Update-AzureDisk : ResourceNotFound : The disk with the specified name does not exist."
I used Login-AzureRmAccount to login using Powershell. I have two subscriptions, I set the correct by using Set-AzureSubscription. 

If I type Get-AzureSubscription,  CurrentStorageAccountName: is blank

Comment: For ASM mode, you should use `Add-Azureaccount` to login your subscription.

Comment: Thanks, this works! Not really related to the main question but how badly would I need a backup for this operation? 

Everything worked fine on same Ubuntu test server installation but now I am planning to run it on the main server. 
And if so, what is the quickest/easiest way to backup my classic deployed vhd?

Comment: @lumenrain Please don't bury additional questions in comments. If you have a new question, please ask as a *question*. What you're asking here about backups have nothing to do with modifying disk sizes.